# Apache NiFi: merge SQL lines into Json

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a SQL database, and I extract some lines, transfrom them into Json to feed a MongoDB. I'm stuck with the transformation step. I have tried this flow:
[image: screenshot]
The process is stalled on the MergeRecord processor, I don't knwo why.

The aim is to transform this kind of (simplified) SQL query result:

```
ID      ROUTE_CODE  STATUS SITE_ID SITE_CODE      
379619  1801300001  10     220429   100001
379619  1801300001  10     219414   014037
379619  1801300001  10     220429   100001
379620  1801300002  10     220429   100001
379620  1801300002  10     219454   014075
379620  1801300002  10     220429   100001
```

To this json:

```
[
  {
    "routeId": "379619",
    "routeCode": "1901300001",
    "routeStatus": "10",
    sites: [
        { "siteId": "220429", "siteCode" : "100001" },
        { "siteId": "219414", "siteCode" : "014037" }           
    ]
  },
  {
    "routeId": "379620",
    "routeCode": "1901300002",
    "routeStatus": "10",
    sites: [
        { "siteId": "220429", "siteCode" : "100001" },
        { "siteId": "219454", "siteCode" : "014075" }           
    ]
  }
]
```

The MergeRecord should group by the "routeId", also I don't know yet the correct Jolt transform to group the sites as array...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The flow is stuck because back-pressure has engaged on the queue between ConvertAvrToJson and MergeRecord, which can be seen by the red indicator showing that the queue has reached its max size of 10k flow files. This means the ConvertAvroToJson processor will no longer execute until the queue's threshold has been reduced, except MergeRecord is likely waiting for more files so the queue isn't going to reduce.

You could change the settings on the queue to increase the threshold to be higher than the number of records you are waiting for, or you could implement the flow differently...

After ExecuteSql it looks like 3 processors are being used to basically split, convert to json, and remerge back together. This could be done a lot more efficiently by not splitting and just using ConvertRecord with an Avro reader and a JSON writer, this way you can go ExecuteSQL -> ConvertRecord -> JOLT.

Also, you may want to look at JoltTransformRecord as an alternative to JoltTransformJson.

Comment: You can also use ExecuteSQLRecord with a JSON Writer instead of ExecuteSQL -> ConvertRecord

Comment: That sounds even better :)

Comment: Thanks for all your comments. I will try with your proposals.

Answer (score 1):

After ExecuteSQL (or ExecuteSQLRecord), you can then use PartitionRecord with the following user-defined properties added (property name is left of `=`, value to the right):

```
routeId = /ROUTE_ID
routeCode = /ROUTE_CODE
routeStatus = /STATUS
```

PartitionRecord should use a JSON writer, then you can use JoltTransformJson with the following spec:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "ID": "routeId",
        "ROUTE_CODE": "routeCode",
        "STATUS": "routeStatus",
        "SITE_ID": "sites[#2].siteId",
        "SITE_CODE": "sites[#2].siteCode"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "routeId": "=firstElement(@(1,routeId))",
      "routeCode": "=firstElement(@(1,routeCode))",
      "routeStatus": "=firstElement(@(1,routeStatus))"
    }
  }
]
```

That will group each of the site IDs/codes into the `sites` field. Then you just need MergeRecord to patch them back together. Unfortunately PartitionRecord doesn't yet support the `fragment.*` attributes (I have written up [NIFI-6139](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-6139) to cover this improvement), so MergeRecord won't be able to guarantee that all the transformed records from the original input file will be in the same merged flow file. However each merged flow file will contain records with the `sites` array for some number of unique `routeId/routeCode/routeStatus` values.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful ! I just wonder if there is a way to avoid the duplicate in the sites array ?

Comment: There is an open Jira case (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-6047) to add a DetectDuplicateRecord processor. In the meantime, you _might_ be able to use QueryRecord to do some kind of `SELECT DISTINCT` with `GROUP BY`. Another less-than-ideal workaround is to use PartitionRecord again on the `siteId` and `siteCode` fields, then QueryRecord on each flow file with `SELECT * FROM FLOWFILE LIMIT 1`